# WPF MVVM Binding refresh to display status

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a 'Load Data' process that could take anywhere from 1 to 20 seconds so I want to display a status message on my window. My window grid has a row which will be visible or hidden based upon a trigger which is bound to my view model. This works great. My problem is how I can change the binding and get the UI to refresh BEFORE my long running task starts. What happens now is that the Status property is set and then I start my task but the UI doesn't get refreshed until AFTER my task is complete. Here's my xaml and view model code.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="4" Background="{StaticResource appPrimaryBackColorLight}" Height="20">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusMessageVisibility}" Value="Collapsed">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="20" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="20" Duration="0:0:.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Width="20" Height="20" Grid.RowSpan="2" ani:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="/Images/spinner_status_20.gif"></Image>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusMessage}" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,1,0,0" Style="{StaticResource appTextBlockSmallDark}" Foreground="White" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>


private void LoadImportData() 
{
    // Show the status message by changing the view model properties
    StatusMessage = "Loading data from import file. Please stand by...";
    StatusMessageVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                          {
                              //This invokes UI specific code inside module initialization
                              LoadDataNow();
                          }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: What do get+set look like for `StatusMessage` and `StatusMessageVisibility`? `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented for both?

Comment: Yes... I'm using MVVM Light and calling RaisePropertyChanged() for each so the view is being notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using the current synchronization context - i.e. the UI thread - for your task. You're not running it on a background thread. Instead, use the default arguments for your worker task which schedule it on a separate thread, and create a continuation for to run on the UI thread. This continuation will update the UI once the task has completed.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                      {
                          //This invokes UI specific code inside module initialization
                          LoadDataNow();
                      });
task.ContinueWith(t => StatusMessageVisibility = Visibility.None, 
                       TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: So here's my problem. My LoadDataNow method grabs data from a file and loads it into a DevExpress GridControl. Unfortunately, even though I don't have this grid placed on a Window, the grid needs to run on the UI thread or I get the error "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."

I'm coming over from the .NET 2.0 world and want better understand and utilize the TPL. I know I can get this to fly using a background worker but using tasks just looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: Load all your data into memory in the background task (this should be the long-running bit), then bind it to the grid control in the continuation. You can't, and shouldn't, mix long-running processes with UI code.

Comment: Thanks Tim but unfortunately that's not an option as the grid interaction is an integral part of my long running process. Here's what i'm doing:
(1) Load a large excel workbook into a datatable
(2) Assign the datatable to the devexpress grid.
(3) Run a lot of filers against the data in the grid (the DevExpress grid is OUTSTANDING between it's advanced filtering and performance which is why I'm using it).
(4) Save the remaining filtered data to my database.

Comment: I have to agree with @TimRogers, you need to rethink how you accomplish this task, the UI code should not be so closely tied to the process.  I can guarantee that the database filtering is faster than the datagrid filtering, and you can save directly from the DB.

Comment: Thanks all for your input as I was able to figure out a way to do what I wanted. @JKing... never guarantee when you don't understand the entire process. No way will you be able to load 50,000 records from excel and push to a VistaDB database across across a network to let the db do the filtering vs filtering locally in a grid when all I need is 2,000 of the 50,000 records stored in the db.